# Call the python file from Java and get the variables

Tags: java, python, jython, runtime.exec

I have a python code, with external imports,  that I want to run from java, example;

```
import pandas
import PuLP,numpy,scipy,matplotlib,Lasagne,Theano

def reporter():
   return "ingo"

required_str = reporter()
required_int = 10
required_array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So, I cannot possibly use Jython, since there are many imports that cannot run in java, so instead I am using "Runtime method" :

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class testconv {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/my/python myfile.py");
         String requiredString;
         int requiredInt;
         String[] requiredArray;
     }
 }
```

So, I want to get the python variables, " required_str/required_int/required_array " assigned to java variables, " requiredString/requiredInt/requiredArray ", so I cannot use BufferReader/InputStream. Is it possible? or else please suggest a method to achieve the desired results.

Comment: and I assume it is always a `string` which is set in `required_str`? Or, Can it be any data type?

Comment: It can be any data type, all I want to do is not to get the output as an InputStream but as a standard data type, like integer, or array or String.